# pixel's exact value from a JPG image in java

Tags: java, image, rgb, pixel

does anyone know how can I get the exact values from JPG image, for example: I have created an image that only contains values from 0 - 255, this image is on gray scale, that means : RGB values are exactly the same. In the other hand I exactly know the value from each pixel in each position, but when I use the getRGB() Im gettin values that does not match with the original values. Eg:

I have a '0' in the position [0][0] the getRGB() is returning a decimal number '13'; in the next position [0][1] I have a '1' but the getRGB() is returning a decimal number '13' too... So guys I know that these values can be because of the compression of the image. But anyone has an idea of what adjust I can make to get the correct values???

I will appreciate any help..

Answer (score 2):

JPEG uses lossy compression algorithm: it sacrafices data precision to achieve better compression. So you can't get back the exact RGB values.

If you need to get back the exact RGB values, use PNG image format which uses lossless compression algorithms.

Also [`BufferedImage.getRGB()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) returns the pixel data quoting from the javadoc:

> Returns an integer pixel in the **default RGB color model** (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace.

So if you have gray values in the range of `0..255`, the RGB values returned by `getRGB()` will be in the range of `0...16777215` (`16777215=0xffffff`). The `int` returned by `getRGB()` is not the gray version but contains the RGB components (and the alpha if it has transparency).